# Django template: using forloop.counter as an index to a list

Tags: django, templates

In a django template, I need to use forloop.counter0 to access an element in a list. For instance:

```
{% for foo in bar %}
   <p>{{data[{{forloop.counter0}}]}}</p>

{%endfor%}
```

That notation doesn't work - I guet "cannot parse the remainder: [{{forloop.....]"

So... how do I use the variable forloop.counter0 as an index for another variable (data) which is a list in a django template?

EDIT: why I think i need to do that.... Short story is that I have an inlineformset. The formset (let's call it "Discounts") is simple - a description (just a label to show users) and a % discount associated. The user only needs to enter the %. That formset is used within a Customer form. Using inlineformset_factory(Customer, Discounts, ....). There are also 2 foreign keys that must be set in that discount form (to the Customer instance being created, and to the MetaGroup, see below). But those are hidden fields and it's easy to do.

However, the number of forms I need in that formset is determined by the instances in another table (let's call it "MetaGroup"). E.g. metagroupe contains entries for stuff like say Chairs, Tables, Sofa. My "Discounts" inlineformset provides users a way to set the discount % on each of those MetaGroup.

Thus in the template I do:

...

```
<tbody>
   <managmeent forms, error stuff here>
   {% for form in formset %} 
      <td>{{form.field.pourcent}}</td>
```

That's the forloop in which I need to access the data[fooloop.counter0]. data is provided by the inclusion I use to render that table/snippet.....

EDIT: the accepted answer is solution to the narrow question - which is that I probably shouldn't do that. For the wider issue (e.g. as to why I thought I needed to do this), I ended up using what is [detailed here](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/forms-fields-based-on-database-content/8317/3).

Comment: Please *don't*. Django templates are *deliberately* restricted, *not* to do this since business logic belongs in the *view*, not the template.

Comment: The full story is that this is meant to populate a table. There's one row per element in the data list. It's just that data is added to the context somewhere else, so I don't have an easy way to do otherwise.

Comment: then you view will need to "prepare" it to a more accessible format. For example a list of lists of data.

Comment: I still don't see why you need `data[fooloop.counter0]`, what is data here? If it is data passed to that form, you access it with `form.data`.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions it would be better for you to show your _view_. Also do you want to do that indexing to render hidden fields for the form? Can't you simply pass that as the _initial_ data to the formset?

Comment: Data contains the description (so the user knows which label/group he's setting a discount to) as well as the foreign key for that form (group item).

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions: you can also add an attribute on the forms in the view, and thus these. In the view it thus looks like `myform.some_attribute = some_value`, and then in the template, you can access it with `{{ myform.some_attribute }}`.

Comment: If I had only one form yes. But I'm using inlineformset_factory. The number of extras/forms depends on how many entries are in my MetaGroup table. I don't understand how I can the tell formsetfactory to essentiallly "take those 12 tuples of information, and give one to each of the 12 extras I want you to build in this formset".

IF this was a single form yes, but in my use case?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions: that does not matter, you can enumerate over the forms in your formset with `for form in myformset:`, and thus let the view fill it in for the different forms in the formset.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions Yes you can provide initial data for formsets. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#id2

Comment: Ok, I think I get you guys there. Once I do fs = MyFormset() in the view, I have all my say 12 forms for my 12 MetaGroups. So I could do as Willem suggested (for f in fs, set f.my_attr = data) and then unpack in the template. Or I could try as Abdul suggested, and use the link in the docs he provided so that I have a data list with 12 elements, that gets passed as initial for my 12 forms in the formset_factory.... is that broadly right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please *don't*. Django templates are *deliberately* restricted, *not* to do this since business logic belongs in the *view*, not the template.

In the view, you can zip `bar` and `data`, so then the view looks like:

```
def my_view(request):
    bar = …
    data = …
    context = {
        'bar_data': zip(bar, data)
    }
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', context)
```

and render this with:

```
{% for foo, datum in bar_data %}
   <p>{{ datum }}</p>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I can do that. I'll edit my question to provide the larger context, why I think I need to do what I am asking for.

Comment: Edited above to add details. But maybe I get what you're saying - do you think I should zip() the forms in my formset along with the associated data for each of the forms in that formset?